# Properties validation failed with message extraneous key is not permitted

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs, ecs-taskdefinition

I am getting the following error

> Properties validation failed for resource mytaskdefinition with message: #/ContainerDefinitions/0: extraneous key [linuxParameters] is not permitted

Per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_ContainerDefinition.html `linuxParameters` is a valid key.

As the error suggests, my task definition nests `linuxParameters` right under ContainerDefinitions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Despite the docs using camel case `linuxParameters`, AWS has suddenly started enforcing capitalization.

**The fix is to capitalize the first letter, ie use `LinuxParameters` instead.**

Note that this applies to nested properties as well, eg `initProcessEnabled` would result in

> #/ContainerDefinitions/0/LinuxParameters: extraneous key [initProcessEnabled] is not permitted

So you would have to use `InitProcessEnabled`.